# Flask Python Login Authentication Failed

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am new to Python Flask. While I was trying to create a simple Login and Logout page, I had encountered failed authentication problem (Correct username with wrong password are able to login). I wasn't very sure where it goes wrong as it was initially working fine. Anyone can enlighten me ?

**views.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, redirect, render_template, url_for
from flask_login import current_user, login_required, login_user

from . import db, login_manager
from .forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm
from .models import WebUser

view = Blueprint("view", __name__)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(username):
    user = WebUser.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    return user or current_user

@view.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def render_login_page():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.is_submitted():
        print("username entered:", form.username.data)
        print("password entered:", form.password.data)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = WebUser.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            # TODO: You may want to verify if password is correct
            login_user(user)
            print(login_user(user))
            return redirect("/homepage")
    return render_template("index.html", form=form)

@view.route("/registration", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def render_registration_page():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        username = form.username.data
        preferred_name = form.preferred_name.data
        password = form.password.data
        query = "SELECT * FROM web_user WHERE username = '{}'".format(username)
        exists_user = db.session.execute(query).fetchone()
        if exists_user:
            form.username.errors.append("{} is already in use.".format(username))
        else:
            query = "INSERT INTO web_user(username, preferred_name, password) VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}')"\
                .format(username, preferred_name, password)
            db.session.execute(query)
            db.session.commit()
            return "You have successfully signed up!"
    return render_template("registration-simple.html", form=form)
    #form is passed in as a model

@view.route("/homepage", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def render_homepage():
    return "<h1>Hello, {}!</h1>".format(current_user.preferred_name or current_user.username)

@view.route("/logout")
@login_required
def render_logout():
    logout_user()
    return render_template("index.html")
```

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, ValidationError

def is_valid_name(form, field):
    if not all(map(lambda char: char.isalpha(), field.data)):
        raise ValidationError('This field should only contain alphabets')

def agrees_terms_and_conditions(form, field):
    if not field.data:
        raise ValidationError('You must agree to the terms and conditions to sign up')

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(
        label='Name',
        validators=[InputRequired(), is_valid_name],
        render_kw={'placeholder': 'Username', 'class': 'input100'}
    )
    preferred_name = StringField(
        label='Preferred name',
        validators=[is_valid_name],
        render_kw={'placeholder': 'Preferred name', 'class': 'input100'}
    )
    password = PasswordField(
        label='Password',
        validators=[InputRequired()],
        render_kw={'placeholder': 'Password', 'class': 'input100'}
    )

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(
        label='Name',
        validators=[InputRequired()],
        render_kw={'placeholder': 'Username', 'class': 'input100'}
    )
    password = PasswordField(
        label='Password',
        validators=[InputRequired()],
        render_kw={'placeholder': 'Password', 'class': 'input100'}
    )
```

**models.py**

```
from . import db    
class WebUser(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    preferred_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return self.username
```

**loginpage.html**

```
<body>

    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('static/images/bg-01.jpg');">
            <div class="wrap-login100 p-t-30 p-b-50">
                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-41">
                    Food Delivery System
                </span>

                <form class="login100-form validate-form p-b-33 p-t-5">
                    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
                        {{ form.username() }}
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xe82a;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
                        <!-- <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"> -->
                        {{ form.password() }}
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xe80f;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-32">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn" formmethod="post">
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">New user? <a href="{{url_for('view.render_registration_page')}}" style="color: tomato;">Register</a></p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could implement the login mechanism:

**views.py**

```
from flask_login import current_user, login_required, login_user

@view.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def render_login_page():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("/homepage")

    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = WebUser.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or user.password != form.password.data:
            # password or user are incorrect then we redirect to the login page.
            return redirect('/')

        login_user(user)
        print(login_user(user))
        return redirect("/homepage")
    return render_template("index.html", form=form)
```

**models.py**

```
from . import db  
from flask_login import UserMixin

class WebUser(UserMixin, db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    preferred_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

Note that I imported the class `UserMixin` of the module `flask_login`.

The `flask-login` extension works with the application's user model and expects certain properties and methods to be implemented in it, like: `is_authenticated`, `is_active`, `is_anonymous` and `get_id`.

For this, the module offers a **mixin** class called  `UserMixin` which contains a generic implementation of these methods, which is suitable for the majority of scenarios.

So you don't have to define them yourself. You can just include the mixin class in your model.

Comment: Note this example stores the user's password in plain text in the database.  In real life a hash of the password should be stored.